# python create dictionary from two list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, dictionary

In my code i am getting values like this

```
keys = request.POST.get('keys')
KeysList = json.loads(keys)
        
values = request.POST.get('values')
valuesList = json.loads(values)
```

After print statement i am getting values in list  like :

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Values = ['true', 'false', 'true', 'true']
```

but what i exactly want is like i want a dictionary in this way :

updateObj = {
'A' : 'true',
'B' : 'false',
'C' : 'true',
'D' : 'true',
}

how can i achieve this can any one please suggest me for this ?? i am stuck here thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension for this:

```py
updatedObj = {key: value for key, value in zip(keys, Values)}
```

OR:

```py
updatedObj = dict(zip(keys, Values)) # even more simpler than dict comprehesion
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: nice one, you can do it even simpler: dict(zip(keys, Values))

Comment: exactly! let me add your suggestion in my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

keys = request.POST.get('keys')
KeysList = json.loads(keys)

```
    values = request.POST.get('values')
    valuesList = json.loads(values)    
    res = {} 
    for key in KeysList: 
        for value in valuesList: 
            res[key] = value 
            valuesList.remove(value) 
            break
```

I found the solution